# InterruptedException not catch?

Tags: java, interrupt, future

I'm trying to implement the Raft Consensus Algorithm for a Distributed System Project, in particular now I'm concentrating about Leader Election Algorithm. Essentially, there are 3 states:

1. Follower
2. Candidate
3. Leader

The state passage is pretty complicate if you don't know the algorithm, and I think that the only useful things to know is that each state perform a different task. So I implemented this classes:

```
public class ServerStateExecutor {
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private ServerState state;
    private Future<?> future;

    public ServerStateExecutor()
    {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        SwitchFollower();
    }

    public void ExecuteState(ServerState state)
    {
        if(future!=null) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
        System.out.println("Submitting...");
        future = executor.submit(state);
    }

    public void SwitchFollower() {
        ExecuteState(new Follower(this));
    }

    public void SwitchCandidate() {
        ExecuteState(new Candidate(this));//if true then no Timeout
    }

    public void SwitchLeader() {
        ExecuteState(new Leader(this));
    }
}

public abstract class ServerState implements Runnable {
    protected ServerStateExecutor executor;

    public abstract void run();
    public ServerState(ServerStateExecutor executor)
    {
        this.executor = executor;
    }
}
```

As you can see, in my implementation when you switch from a state to another one, first you (try to) "kill" the task relative to the actual state, and then you submit the task relative to the new state.

I will post a "stupid" implementation of the task performed in the Follower and Candidate states:

```
public class Follower extends ServerState {

    public Follower(ServerStateExecutor executor) {
        super(executor);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
            executor.SwitchCandidate();
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println("INTERRUPTION!");}
    }
}

public class Candidate extends ServerState {

    public Candidate(ServerStateExecutor executor) {
        super(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted!");
        }
        executor.SwitchFollower();
    }
}
```

Now, as you can imagine while I execute `Follower.run()` the variable `future` is referring to the task `Follower.run()`. So why if I call `SwitchCandidate` during `Follower.run()` the `InterruptException` thrown by `future.cancel(true)` is not catch by `Follower.run()`?

In other words, why`Follower.run()` doesn't catch the interruption thrown by itself?

Comment: Instead of `future.cancel(true);` use `future.interrupt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Interrupting a Thread**

> If any thread is in sleeping or waiting state (i.e. sleep() or wait()
>   is invoked), calling the interrupt() method on the thread, breaks out
>   the sleeping or waiting state throwing InterruptedException. If the
>   thread is not in the sleeping or waiting state, calling the
>   `interrupt()` method performs normal behaviour and doesn't interrupt the
>   thread but sets the interrupt flag to true.

Example of doing So :

```
class TestInterruptingThread1 extends Thread{  
public void run(){  
try{  
Thread.sleep(1000);  
System.out.println("task");  
}catch(InterruptedException e){  
throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted..."+e);  
}  

}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
TestInterruptingThread1 t1=new TestInterruptingThread1();  
t1.start();  
try{  
t1.interrupt();  
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Exception handled "+e);}  

}  
}
```